# Rosbag filter memory error

Tags: ros, filter, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My hardware: Intel NUC8i7BEHI, with 16Gb or RAM and a SSD.
My software: ROS1 Kinetic Desktop-Full, Ubuntu 16.04.6 Xenial, Python 2.7.12.
I am getting the following error while I try to filter a bag (`rosbag filter input.bag output.bag "topic in ['/topic1','/topic2','/topic3']"`):

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rosbag", line 35, in <module> rosbag.rosbagmain()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 896, in rosbagmain cmdscmd
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 362, in filter_cmd msg.deserialize(serialized_bytes)
File "/tmp/genpy_hai_6g/tmpjn80x2.py", line 162, in deserialize end += struct.calcsize(pattern)
MemoryError
```

What I found is that I get the following error in random bags. The size or the duration of the bags do not matter. It also stops at random % of completion. Probably that random is something that I currently do not understand.
What is strange is that the memory is not surpassing 4.5 GB. While doing the `free -h` command, I can see a minimum of 10GB available of memory right before the error stops the program.

Thanks for the help!

Update: while running with `strace` I get the following:

> _llseek(4, 1771724800, [1771724800], SEEK_SET) = 0
> _llseek(4, 1771724800, [1771724800], SEEK_SET) = 0 read(4,
> "9]X\276\360\17)\0\0\0\252\n\0\0\350S9]\237>\354\17\t\0\0\0base_l"...,
> 4096) = 4096
> _llseek(4, 1771728896, [1771728896], SEEK_SET) = 0
> _llseek(4, 1771728896, [1771728896], SEEK_SET) = 0 write(3,
> "&\0\0\0\r\0\0\0time=\350S9]\223\t\274\17\t\0\0\0conn=\2\0"...,
> 367) = 367 fstat64(3,
> {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664,
> st_size=806901049, ...}) = 0
> _llseek(3, 806899712, [806899712], SEEK_SET) = 0 read(3,
> "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...,
> 4096) = 1337
> _llseek(4, 1771728896, [1771728896], SEEK_SET) = 0 read(4,
> "\276\320\37\231\317\276\0\37\231\317\276\0\37\231\317\276\0\37\231\317\276\2\37\231\317\276
> \37\231\317\276\260"..., 126226432) =
> 126226432 read(4,
> "\37\231\317\2760\37\231\317\276\2\37\231\317\276\2\37\231\317\276\0\37\231\317\276\r\37\231\317\276\r\37\231"...,
> 4096) = 4096 mmap2(NULL, 1514790912,
> PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
> MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =
> 0x4ca80000 mmap2(NULL, 126234624,
> PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
> MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =
> 0x7e5000 mmap2(NULL, 504930304,
> PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
> MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1
> ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
> brk(0x65b00000)
> = 0x47956000 mmap2(NULL, 505061376, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
> MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1
> ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
> mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE,
> MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE,
> -1, 0) = 0xb2a1c000 munmap(0xb2a1c000, 933888)              = 0
> munmap(0xb2c00000, 114688)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329252/rosbag-filter-memory-error/) by [Murcamil](https://answers.ros.org/users/44258/murcamil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
As an update, I realized that I have installed the wrong Ubuntu - i386 version. I should have installed the 64bit version - AMD does not mean the company AMD but rather the CPU type.
After reinstalling all, the error did not appear.

---

Originally posted by [Murcamil](https://answers.ros.org/users/44258/murcamil/) with karma: 16 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0